# dynamic django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to use the dynamic django form script from 
http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/714/

The dynamic form is generated, but I am having hard time retrieving submitted fields through `form.cleaned_data['myfield']`

There are few comments on the snippet page, those didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that you have called is_valid() on the form first, and that the field is passing it's validation routines?

Comment: thanks, it works with this at bottom
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():